# writing to 2 schemas in one database with one datasource, using Spring and Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jta, atomikos

We have two schemas in one oracle database. We are writing a Spring/Hibernate application, which will write to tables in both schemas in one operation.

My question is: Can ***one*** datasource write to both schemas, in one transaction, and  rollback all updates in both schemas if required?

We are in a non Java EE environment, using just Tomcat, so there is no out of the box support for Global Transactions/JTA. I know, if Global Transactions are required, we could utilize Springs support for JTA (and Atomikos).

However, are Global Transactions required in the above situation.. as both schemas are in one database? Is this a use case for JTA?